# Connect Chiba xForm to a restful web service (exist db)

Tags: exists, xforms

I need to read an xml instance from an exist db.
I am attempting to connect chiba to a restful web service via the following command:

```
        <xf:model>
 <xf:instance id="data-instance"
                src="http://myhost:8081/exist/rest/test/" />
</xf:model>
```

However, I get the following error message when I load the xform:

```
    Object model not supported  

Stack Trace:

org.chiba.xml.xforms.exception.XFormsLinkException: object model not supported
 at org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Instance.fetchData(Instance.java:625)
 at org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Instance.createInitialInstance(Instance.java:580)
 at org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Instance.init(Instance.java:83)
 at org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Model.createInstanceObject(Model.java:828)
 at org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Model.modelConstruct(Model.java:794)
 at org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Model.per
```

Reviewing the error log reveals the following additional error messages:

```
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:595)
2010-04-06 17:09:29,423 WARN  [org.apache.commons.httpclient.cookie.CookieSpec]
: Invalid cookie state: domain not specified
 2010-04-06 17:09:29,423 WARN  [org.chiba.connector.http.HTTPURIResolver] : URI:
 http://myhost:8081/exist/rest/test/ couldn't be
resolved
 2010-04-06 17:09:29,423 WARN  [org.chiba.xml.xforms.Container] : handle event e
xception: org.chiba.xml.xforms.exception.XFormsLinkException kept for rethrowal
after dispatch() has finished
 2010-04-06 17:09:29,423 WARN  [org.chiba.xml.xforms.Container] : XForms Error:
object model not supported
 2010-04-06 17:09:29,423 ERROR [org.chiba.xml.xforms.core.Model] : [xf:model:C1]
 link exception: {targetId=C1, defaultinfo=http://myhost
:8081/exist/rest/test/, targetName=model}
 2010-04-06 17:09:29,423 ERROR [org.chiba.xml.xforms.Container] : dispatch: exce
ption during event flow
```

I am able to access the url via Orbeon so I know the url is correct. Any thoughts why I'm having issues connecting from chiba?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a networking issue. Is Chiba running in the same machine as Orbeon? Can you ping myhost from Chiba machine? Can you open the same URL in browser? Maybe there is an authentication issue (judging from your previous post). The URL doesn't seem to refer to .xml file - does it return XML when you open it in browser?

Comment: it doesn't appear to be a network issue. i can connect to machine and even access the url from my web browser.